# asynchronous task android.. what to do?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RssActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(NEKI_STRING,listItems.get(position).getLink().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
        }
```

SO i have this event on ItemClick i want to start my activity BUT i want to put it in a  private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask because my teacher wants it not to crash when there is no internet connection. So Is there another way around and how do i implement AsyncTask, i tried to copy/paste the Intent as seen here in the TryCatch Block of the AsyncTask function but it didn't work it just crashed.

Comment: your `onItemClick` looks just fine (provided `listItems` is not null and contains valid items),  if the app is crashing in `RssActivity`, handle that crash in that class, so post the stacktrace of the crash and the  relevant code from `RssActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can used this method to check for internet connection :

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

then you use it in an async task just like the teacher wants it to be ..

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    private Context context;
    private String NEKI_STRING;
    private String listItemString;

    public AsyncTaskRunner(Context context ,String neki_string, String listItemString){

        this.context = context;
        NEKI_STRING = neki_string;
        this.listItemString = listItemString;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        if(isNetworkAvailable(context)){


            return "OK";


        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String reply) {
        super.onPostExecute(reply);

        if(reply.equals("OK")) {
            try{
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RssActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(NEKI_STRING,listItemString);
            startActivity(intent);
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
```

}

The async task not that it is needed but since you need to implement it.

Then you run your async task :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            new AsyncTaskRunner(getApplicationContext(), NEKI_STRING, listItems.get(position).getLink().toString()).execute();
    }
```